# Storing data on Hash Map (While loop)

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Hey guys i'm working on a coursework, where i need to store details every time the user inputs them into the main. This code is written in java. The issue is I don't exactly understand how the HashMap works...

This is my main program:

```
SortNodeDetails sort = new SortNodeDetails();
sort.AddNodeDetails(typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, resources);
sort.printUnsorted();
```

This is my class SortNodeDetails:

```
public class SortNodeDetails {
    static int alph = 0;
    public static boolean ASC = true;

   Map<String, NodeDetails> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();

void AddNodeDetails(String typeMessage, String nodeName, String ip, String nPort, int rCapacity, String resources) {
    NodeDetails node = new NodeDetails(typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, resources);
    alph++;
    String numberAsString = Integer.toString(alph);
    unsortMap.put(numberAsString, node);

}
void printUnsorted() {
    printMap(unsortMap);
}
public static void printMap(Map<String, NodeDetails> map)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, NodeDetails> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue().getNPort());
    }
}
```

My NodeDetails is a basic class:

```
public class NodeDetails {
private String typeMessage;
private String nodeName;
private String ip;
private String nPort;
private int capacity;
private String resources;

get and set methods for all the variables as well....

}
```

Currently this code only prints the last input and not all the inputs stored in the hash map.
Is the issue in my print (for loop) or the way im storing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your code, your `main` method *should* look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortNodeDetails sort = new SortNodeDetails();
    while(condition) {
       /*
        * set user inputs to typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, and resources
        */
        sort.AddNodeDetails(typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, resources);
    }
    sort.printUnsorted();
}
```

But, because you did not provide very much info for how your `main` method looks, I have no way of knowing. If you have the code that you provided so that your `main` method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(condition) {
       /*
        * set user inputs to typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, and resources
        */
    }
    SortNodeDetails sort = new SortNodeDetails();
    sort.AddNodeDetails(typeMessage, nodeName, ip, nPort, rCapacity, resources);
    sort.printUnsorted();
}
```

(which is what my interpretation of your description is) Then you will only see the one item in your `HashMap` because you only added one item when you only call `AddNodeDetails` once.

---

For printing the Map, I hope you are using Java 8 by now :) If so, you can print a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) using `forEach` + lambda expression.

```
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v.getNPort()));
```

The type of `k` is `String` and the type of `v` is `NodeDetails`. But, I don't think that's what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

You added a single entry in the map.
So you loop a single time as expected.
Actually you print only the `port` field of the `NodeDetails` instance that you created and added in the map as a value :

```
 System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue().getNPort());
```

To create a String representing a `NodeDetails` object, override `toString()` in `NodeDetails` and pass directly the object in `println()` :

```
System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Ik i'm only printing the Port field... I have create a while loop in the main program. The user is asked for the details multiple times but when they decide to exit the loop.  I want it to print all the details previously entered by the user but unfortunately it only prints the last input. @davidxxx